# Reference Request: Suitability of a text and corresponding video lecture series request for "Matroid Theory"

Tags: reference-request, textbooks

I am an undergraduate student from the CS background.

While reading a portion of the text *"Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et. al.* I came across a section of **Matroids**. I was unable to understand it properly as I have not been lucky enough to have a formal matroid course.

I was recommended the following book *"Matroid Theory" by John Oxley* in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748367/606943). Now I find the above book labelled as *"Oxford Graduate Text In Mathematics"* ,so with my current knowledge of as an undergraduate CS student (just completed 2nd year) I do not quite know whether I shall be able to comprehend the text, more-over the text is not quite short (a total of 719 page in the second edition). Moreover with the current tightness of the present curriculum, I cannot simply afford to start a text and leave it half way being unable to understand (it shall cause frustration).

So I request here to guide me as to whether I shall be able to understand the book given my current qualification. Moreover could a video lecture series be recommended to me so that I shall easily understand the concepts of matroid (in a considerably short time, given that I am planning to do self study and I shall not have any teacher support, without a teacher resolving doubts takes time).

Answer (score 2):

> Wilson, Robin J. "An introduction to matroid theory." *The American Mathematical Monthly* 80, no. 5 (1973): 500-525.
> [JStor link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319608?seq=1).

This is an elementary introduction, not even assuming much knowledge of graph theory. He explains enough transversal theory to proceed to matroids. He defines a matroid in several ways, so that you get different perspectives.

Of course it is out-of-date, but it is quite accessible, and might allow you to then move on to more recent expositions.
For example,
this text is explicitly written for undergraduates:

> Gordon, Gary, and Jennifer McNulty. *Matroids: A Geometric Introduction*. Cambridge University Press, 2012.
> [Cambridge link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/matroids-a-geometric-introduction/2DCAB3A148C84F5DB32E1E398AD7A6FD).

---

[image]

---